# I should be able to use cell value (database connection details) in my macro function to connect to DB

Tags: excel, database-connection, cell, vba

I have managed to pull data from DB with the help of Macros. But I have a difficulty now, I should be able to use the servername and database authentication in the spreadsheet that i have provided in the spreadsheet rather than providing in macro VB coding. 
I have also got the content of the cells using macro. But I have problems in using that value in the macro function. I am not able to connect to DB. 
Kindly help.

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
MsgBox "Welcome to the Macro for getting SQL queried DB Data from MS Excel"


Dim Servername As String
Dim Databasename As String
Dim UserID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim Query As String


Servername = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
Databasename = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
UserID = Sheet1.Range("A3").Value
Password = Sheet1.Range("A4").Value
Query = Sheet1.Range("A5").Value '

MsgBox Servername
MsgBox Databasename
MsgBox UserID
MsgBox Password
MsgBox Query

    'Declare variables'
        Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
        Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

        Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
        Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    'Open Connection'
        objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Servername;Initial Catalog=Databasename;User ID=UserID;Password=Password;"
        objMyConn.Open

    'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
        Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
        objMyCmd.CommandText = "Query;"
        objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    'Open Recordset'
        Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
        objMyRecordset.Open

    'Copy Data to Excel'
        Sheet3.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objMyRecordset
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate Connection text and your variable values using ampersands:

```
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & Servername & ";Initial Catalog=" & Databasename & ";User ID=" & UserID & " ;Password=" & Password & ";"
```